# Microsoft AspNetCore Environment Variables

Tags: c#, iis, hosting, environment

I've been searching for a way to access the default value for "HttpReques.PathBase".
Since that is configured in the applicationhost.config, I found out pretty quickly, that this must be somehow provided through the hosting environment.
Turns out there is an environment variable for that "ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH".

However... I was searching for some class, nuget package, microsoft documentation or anything that provides a list of all those constant IIS environment variable keys, including explanations on what exactly they provide.
Unfortunately that search was as successfull as bulletproof glass on musks cybertruck presentation, which is why i decided to create my own class for those constants:

(I hope this helps some people...)

```
 /// <summary>
/// Provides the keys of environment variables.
/// </summary>
public static class C_Env
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the matching value from environment variable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Value of environment variable as string.</returns>
    public static string Envalue(this string environmentKey)
    {
        try
        {
            return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentKey);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the keys of AspNetCore specific environment variables, including .net 5 and above. <br/>
    /// Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere at the moment... so... crap. <br/>
    /// Call
    /// "<a cref="System.Environment">System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();</a>" 
    /// in Debug to see all environment variables. 
    /// </summary>
    public static class AspNetCore 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the default path base of the application. <br/>
        /// The set pathbase will be available through 
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.pathbase">
        /// HttpRequest.PathBase. 
        /// </a>
        /// <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The default path base as <a cref="string">String</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string DefaultPathBase = "ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the IIS Web Socket support. <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// <a cref="bool">Bool</a> indicating whether IIS WebSockets are supported by the current environment or not. 
        /// </returns>
        public const string WebSocketSupport = "ASPNETCORE_IIS_WEBSOCKETS_SUPPORTED";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the physical path of the IIS application. <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The physical path as <a cref="string">String</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string PhysicalPath = "ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the IIS HTTP authentication type. <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The authentication type as <a cref="string">String</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string HttpAuth = "ASPNETCORE_IIS_HTTPAUTH";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the IIS https port of this application.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The https port as <a cref="int">int</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string HttpsPort = "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the AspNetCore port.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The AspNetCore port as <a cref="int">int</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string AspNetCorePort = "ASPNETCORE_PORT"; //WTF does this provide? like... a fallback port?

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the content root path of the web application. <br/>
        /// The set pathbase will be available through 
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.contentrootpath">
        /// IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
        /// </a>
        /// <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The default path base as <a cref="string">String</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string ContentRootPath = "ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the https port of the AspNetCore Module for IIS. <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The https port of the AspNetCore module as <a cref="int">int</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string AncmHttpsPort = "ASPNETCORE_ANCM_HTTPS_PORT";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the AspNetCore token. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The AspNetCore Token as <a cref="Guid">GUID</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string Token = "ASPNETCORE_TOKEN"; //WTF does this provide? Bearer Token stuff?

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the AspNetCore environment key. (examples: "Development", "Staging")<br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The AspNetCore environment key as <a cref="string">string</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string Environment = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT";

        /// <summary>
        /// The environment key for the AspNetCore hosting startup assemblies. <br/>
        /// <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration">
        /// Check this documentation for further details.
        /// </a>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The AspNetCore hosting startup assemblies as <a cref="string">string</a>.
        /// </returns>
        public const string HostingStartupAssemblies = "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES";
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I still couldn't find out all information for all those variables... Can some captains please help me complete this list/documentation?

Comment: The only centralized places to learn the existence of those variables are, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/RequestHandlerLib/environmentvariablehash.h and https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/OutOfProcessRequestHandler/serverprocess.h

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for these links! :) I was afraid this would be the answer... 
However I still have hope, that some heros can fill a couple gaps in the list above, without me having to go through AspNetCore spaghetti code...

Comment: You should treat this as an opportunity for yourself. 1. blog about it. 2. Create helper library on GitHub/NuGet. 3. Send feedback to Microsoft so that they might improve documentation on their side, https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues

Answer (score -1):

So, [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/) you can find all the things, on the left side you can see various of links, just expand something and see child elements of some tag.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've looked through that documentation, before posting my question here. Truth is, the documentation is very long and I may have overlooked/overread things... and i may have not expressed my question well enough. My problem is that I need a documentation "access the environment config values in C#". While they do mention environment variables, they do not mention the exact variables they provide (which would those in the class above). So the info i need is: Which  provided variable, referes to which documentation section? (and THAT i could not find out for some of them...)

Comment: Oh, okay, i think i got you.
In .NET we don't have such a thing like "env variables", we can tag something like that, but actually we don't have.  Instead we have settings - it can be reached by click "Properties" on project. There you can manipulate with them. Also, that's the reason why you can't find information - you have been searching for something that actually can`t be in .Net
And about "where can i find" - actually everybody can declare his own settings, so that question must be in group with another question about some lib or framework - "which settings exist in ..."

Comment: Dude... of course we have "environment variables" in .Net Apps... Though I gotta admin they are a little confusing, since they are not only provided by the Operating System, but also through various configuration of the hosting environment. But they still are environment variables... I mean... Thats like a core feature of System.Environment and has been around since... C#?!